# API for create account in Ionic 3 Framework - php magento2

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic3, magento2.2

Below is the Signup html code with, firstname, lastname, email and password fields.

```
...
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>First Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="userData.fname"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
...
<button ion-button full color="buttoncolor" class="signup" (click)="signup()">Signup</button>
```

Belows is the signup.ts file, Below Signup function is called when signup button is clicked.

```
responseData : any;
userData = {
'customer': {
    "email":"",
    "firstname":"",
    "lastname":"",
    "storeId":1,
    "websiteId":1
},
"password":""
};

signup() {
//REST API connection to Magento 2 for Siging up a new customer
//this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.userData, "signup").then((result) => {
  this.responseData = result;
  console.log(this.responseData);
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}, (err) => {
  //connection failed error message
});
}
```

The users are successfully inserted into to Database, but i am not getting the response,

In the signup function when i do console.log(this.responseData); this line returns NULL.

Where am i going wrong ??

Comment: Does your (Magento) signup endpoint return some data?

Comment: yes it returns an object. I am using PHP and curl for inserting the data to Database

Comment: Can you show the `authServiceProvider.postData` method? and the class

Comment: postData(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: new HttpHeaders() }).subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
  }